# HTML multiple table column issue

Tags: html, css, inline

I have one question regarding the HTML tables that I couldn't manage to find myself.

Is it possible to create this layout using HTML and inline css within one table?

[image]

I tried to merge my cells in 4th row (I've started with 3 column layout) because I need 2 cells, and if my table width is 640px, and I force 320px for both cells, whole table gets messed up.

EDIT: 4th row is the issue, I need 2 equal width cells in it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a colspan on 3rd row, 4th row is my problem. I can't get 2 equal width cells in it.

Comment: can you make us a jsfiddle?

Comment: If you want that sort of layout, the odds are you shouldn't be using a table in the first place.

Comment: I need to use tables, it's HTML mailing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All cells in the same column have to be the same width, so you need an extra column:

- First row:  one cell colspan=4
- second row: one cell, on cell colspan=2, one cell
- Third row: one cell colspan=4
- Fourth row: one cell colspan=2, one cell colspan=2

The widths for each column then look something like:

- Column 1 is narrow, let's say width=50px
- Column 2 is 320 - column1's width, 280px
- Column 3 same as 2, 280px
- Column 4 same as 1, e.g. 50px

Comment: Thanks, I will choose this one as a right answer because you answered my question first.

Answer (score 2):

```
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td colspan="2">Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Cell</td>
    <td colspan="2">Cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td colspan="2">cell</td>
            <td>cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">cell</td>
            <td colspan="2">cell</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1" width="100%">   
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4">Cell</td>   
   </tr>   
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">Cell</td>
    <td colspan="2">Cell</td>
    <td width="10%">Cell</td>   
   </tr>   
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4">Cell</td>   
  </tr>   
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" width="50%">Cell</td>
    <td colspan="2" width="50%">Cell</td>   
 </tr>
```

Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gfpq1so7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use like this. it works

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
    td{
        text-align:center;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <table width="640" cellspacing="5">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td colspan="2">Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Cell</td>
        <td colspan="2">Cell</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```